# advanced hotspot settings in android 5.1

Tags: tethering

After upgrading to Android 5.1.1 I have some issues with the hotspot. It works, most of the time, however at what seem to be random times it just switches off. I once half saw a message as this happened, but I only saw "Switching of hotspot because...". So I think it's a feature, not a bug. It might be related to my phone losing internet connection, as I use the hotspot on the train with poor connection quality.

In previous Android versions, I knew how to find advanced Hotspot settings. In this version, I only find very basic settings, like network name and password.

I have CyanogenOS 12.1 / Android 5.1.1 on a 1+1.
Sorry if this question has been asked before, I did not find anything recent anywhere.

Update: I saw the message on switching off now. My cell phone loses network connection, and the hotspot remains on. When it is back within cover the message reads "Switching off hotspot because SIM service change". So I'm guessing it's some kind of protection against getting overcharged for data use.
(Andyes, the laptop remains connected to the hotspot until it gets turned off)

Answer (score 1):

Aparently this is a known bug in the latest Cyanogen (12.1) which should be fixed in the next release.

http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/116964-hotspot-disabled-due-to-sim-subscription-change/